# Saving form data when switching between sites

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, forms

On my online shop, I have one very big form. It contains data and photos of hundreds of products, therefore I don't want to display everything on one site. Instead, products will be split into categories.

When users finish choosing products from one category and switch to another category, I want all choice data from all categories to be saved. **What is the easiest and most efficient way to do this?**
Saving it in `$_SESSION`? In Database via PHP? In Database via `Ajax/PHP`?

All answers I found concern either single forms or online shops with shopping carts. My shop is somewhere in between.

Side note: I'm not good at Ajax yet, so I'd prefer to avoid it, even though I understand that it might be the most elegant solution.

Any idea?

Comment: if you are using jquery serialize the whole form and save into localstorage of the browser.

Comment: Thanks! I would still have to use PHP/MySQL in case a user doesn't use javascript, right? Anyway, I like the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends in how extensive you want to help your customers or potential customers i think.

I think it's safe to say that there are 2 large opposites here. You have Guests on one hand, and Users on the other. Depending on which functionality your website allows, you can take a more specific approach.

If you're working with a `100%` guests user base, i think it would be best to just store everything in the `$_SESSION`.

On the other hand if you're working with mostly users, you will have to make your memory a bit more stable than the vaporising $_SESSION. In this case i would opt for a database that links your users to items they are interested in.

This last option is also viable with `jQuery` to prevent massive amounts of loads in between pages.

Edit:
Regardless of what you pick, look into AJAX nonetheless. It scared me to death at the start too, but it is really straight forward and it is immensely powerful.

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Session. Session is used for storing session data, this is indeed session data.
I think a MySQL database is overload!

file a.php

```
<?php
// file a.php
// ...
// do some form output
echo '<form action="b.php" method="POST"> ... </form>';
?>
```

file b.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// do some session id get / set...
// ...
// fetch data and store
// make sanity checks (e.g. check if there are sql-injections)
$_SESSION['user_choice_cat_xy'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_choice_field']);
// Output cat b
echo '<form action="c.php" method="POST">...</form>'
?>
```